# Assigning new column name and creating new column conditionally in pandas not working?

Tags: python-2.7, pandas, numpy, dataframe, conditional-statements

I have a simple dataframe with pandas, then I rename the variable names into 'a' and 'b'.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({'Type':list('ABBC'), 'Set':list('ZZXY')})
df.columns = ['a', 'b']
print df
df['color'] = np.where(df['b']=='Z', 'green', 'red')
print df

   a  b
0  Z  A
1  Z  B
2  X  B
3  Y  C
   a  b color
0  Z  A   red
1  Z  B   red
2  X  B   red
3  Y  C   red
```

Without the renaming line df.columns, I get

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({'Type':list('ABBC'), 'Set':list('ZZXY')})
#df.columns = ['a', 'b']
#print df
df['color'] = np.where(df['Set']=='Z', 'green', 'red')
print df

  Set Type  color
0   Z    A  green
1   Z    B  green
2   X    B    red
3   Y    C    red
```

I want and would expect the first set of code to produce "green green red red", but it failed and I don't know why.

Comment: `np.where(df['b']=='Z', 'green', 'red')` Shouldn't it be `np.where(df['a']=='Z', 'green', 'red')`?

Comment: Hmmm, it seems to work after switching to 'a', but I don't understand why, didn't I reassign column "Type" into "a" and column "Set" into "b"? Or does "Set" go before "Type" because of alphabetical order?

Comment: column a has characters 'X, Y, Z' whereas b has 'A, B C'. Making comparison `df['b']=='Z'` of course always returns `False`. I think you just misread column a with b. :)

Comment: You're passing a dict as the data, as such the column order is not guaranteed to be the column order of your df this is where your confusion arises

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As pointed out in the comments, the problem comes from how you are rename the columns. You are better off renaming, like so:

```
df = df.rename( columns={'Set': 'a','Type': 'b'})
```